# Shifting from .NET to Win32 development

Tags: .net, c++, winapi

I have been a .NET developer since I started coding. I would like to learn Win32 programming. Need advice on where to start. What are the best resources /books for learining Win32 programming. I know a bit 'college C++'.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948686/any-tutorials-for-win32-sdk-programming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212559/c-win32-gui-programming-the-shortest-path, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329776/a-good-book-to-understand-winapi-programming/329789, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342729/learning-the-win32-api/342740

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in UI development, the best book for direct Win32 development in C or C++ (no MFC) is [Programming Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) by Charles Petzold

For other sorts of Win32 development, such as threading, memory, DLL's, etc., [Windows via C/C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240) by Jeffrey Richter is a great book.

For general Windows architecture, [Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301) by David Solomon and Mark Russinovich is a great resource.

Answer (score 7):

Hands down, best book for Win32 programming is Charles Petzold's book "Programming Windows".  Amazon link [here](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=157231995X).

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in learning C++ have a look around the site, there's loads of questions similar to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155762/best-c-resource

If you want to program windows I'd stick with .net, win32 and MFC are hard work.

Answer (score 0):

While you're at it, pick up this book:

[C++ Pointers and Dynamic Memory Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471049980)

It's old (circa 1995) but it's one of the best books to demystify pointers. If you ever found yourself blindly adding *'s or &'s to get your code to compile you probably need to read this.

Comment: If you ever found yourself blindly adding *s or &s to get your code to compile, you probably need to switch careers.