# What are good resources to learn about creating a custom WS_CAPTION style for Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

I want to learn more about creating my own, custom WS_CAPTION style, the end of which would allow me to build a custom CMainFrame for my application that will respond appropriately to Windows 7 drag events. Any books, web sites, etc that people recommend for learning this kind of thing?

Comment: This SO Question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212559/c-win32-gui-programming-the-shortest-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Petzolds [Programming Windows](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Windows-5th-Book-Package/dp/157231995X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264198958&sr=8-1) is probably a good start. It's *very* extensive.